# Java SAX Xml parasing

Tags: java, xml, sax

I hate asking questions or asking someone to do it for me but Ive wasted 4 days trying to understand how to Sax Xml Parasing works.:

```
public class SAXTest extends DefaultHandler {

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws Exception {
        String webServiceURL = "https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4118648&vCode=ehJMH9zOLu9JYtzxXnO9GEXVNR0Xc3T0Od2H3ijiBtuX4na2NEDp7lvAkXhE0jhs";
        URL geoLocationDetailXMLURL = new URL(webServiceURL);
        URLConnection geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection = geoLocationDetailXMLURL.openConnection();
        geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.setReadTimeout(120000);
        BufferedReader geoLeocationDetails = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(geoLeocationDetails);
        /* saxParser.parse(inputSource, handler);*/






        XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        SAXTest handler = new SAXTest();
        xr.setContentHandler(handler);
        xr.setErrorHandler(handler);

        // Parse each file provided on the
        // command line.
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            FileReader r = new FileReader(args[i]);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(r));
        }
    }


    public SAXTest() {
        super();
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Event handlers.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    public void startDocument() {
        System.out.println("Start document");
    }


    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("End document");
    }


    public void startElement(String uri, String name,
    String qName, Attributes atts) {
        if ("".equals(uri)) System.out.println("Start element: " + qName);
        else System.out.println("Start element: {" + uri + "}" + name);
    }


    public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName) {
        if ("".equals(uri)) System.out.println("End element: " + qName);
        else System.out.println("End element:   {" + uri + "}" + name);
    }


    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        System.out.print("Characters:    \"");
        for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++) {
            switch (ch[i]) {
                case '\\':
                    System.out.print("\\\\");
                    break;
                case '"':
                    System.out.print("\\\"");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    System.out.print("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    System.out.print("\\r");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    System.out.print("\\t");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print(ch[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\"\n");
    }

}
```

This is the code I have so far but i need to grab the data like

```
<row name="Grasume Crendraven" characterID="92916469" corporationName="Hyperion Guard" corporationID="98372642" allianceID="99005157" allianceName="Winmatar Republic" factionID="0" factionName="" /> information into strings like 
       String characters;
       String characterID;
       String corporationName;
       String corporationID;
       String allianceID;
       String allianceName;
       String factionID;
       String factionName;
```

But I have no clue what Im doing this is a new part of Java for me.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just print the data to the console or do you need to process it further?

Comment: this site has information i want to grab like the character name , character id , corporation name, and then be able to use the information else where in my program https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4118648&vCode=ehJMH9zOLu9JYtzxXnO9GEXVNR0Xc3T0Od2H3ijiBtuX4na2NEDp7lvAkXhE0jhs

Comment: If after four days you have no clue what you are doing, then you need to think about improving your learning strategy. Four days is plenty of time to read the relevant sections of a couple of good books: I would particularly recommend Eliotte Rusty Harold's book on XML and Java.

Comment: I'd provide your handler class an object to put the data into (maybe a list of some object type that you define).  When parsing is complete, your list will have the data, and you can pull it out of the handler.  Also, it looks like most of the information you're interested in is in the `Attributes` parameter of `startElement`

Comment: @teolha the end result is for me to be able to grab the data from the url ( https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4118648&vCode=ehJMH9zOLu9JYtzxXnO9GEXVNR0Xc3T0Od2H3ijiBtuX4na2NEDp7lvAkXhE0jhs) the goal for me is to be able to grab the first section in the row set which contains user name and user Id. Then be able to use the user name and id else where in my java program.